# Build issues with ignite

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ignite

I just started using Ignite, version 1.8.0. Everything worked good in the Eclipse IDE but when I started building the project to deploy I ran into this error:

```
ignite-indexing-1.8.0.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

and

```
h2-1.4.191.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

That was a message from Ant.

Any idea what could be the issue? Searching the internet doesn't have much on this topic.

Comment: I continued to investigate the issue and found the above jar files downloaded by Maven to be larger in size compared to those that were packaged with Ignite runtime.

I replaced the Maven downloaded versions with the ones that were packaged with Ignite and it worked. I still haven't figured out what was wrong with Maven downloaded jars.

Comment: Is it still not working with Maven? Do you have your own repo or download from Maven Central?

Comment: I stopped working with Maven in my GWT project due to certains issues and not having enough time to resolve them. There was another Maven project that downloaded those jars, from Maven central. When I used those version of jars I ran into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JARs downloaded from Maven are somehow broken. You can try to clean local repository and try again.